# Error while reading data from webpage in java?

Tags: java, latex, ioexception

I am using this code to read data from a webpage :

```
public class ReadLatex {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String urltext = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=1+2%20\frac{3}{4}";
    URL url = new URL(urltext);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url
            .openStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        // Process each line.
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
   }
}
```

The webpage gives the image for a latex code in the URL.

I am getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
at ReadLatex.main(ReadLatex.java:11)
```

Can anyone tell why I am having this problem and what should be the solution for this?

Comment: 400 means Bad request - It means request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax....did you try some other url ??

Comment: you should escape all your special characters and slash in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a \ (backslash) in a string which in Java is a escape character. To get an actual \ you need to have two of them in your string. So:

```
Wanted text: part1\part2
```

you need to have

```
String theString = "part1\\part2";
```

So you actually want

```
String urltext = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=1+2%20\\frac{3}{4}";
```

Also, when you succeed with your request you get back an image (png) which should not be read with a reader which will try to interpret the bytes as characters using some encoding and this will break the image data. Instead, use the input stream and write the content (bytes) to a file.

A simple example without error handling

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String urltext = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=1+2%20\\frac{3}{4}";
    URL url = new URL(urltext);

    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("TheImage.png");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[8*1024];
    int readSize;
    while ( (readSize = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, readSize);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Sir, I have tried new code but in console it shows unreadable characters .I read your answer but couldnt make out how to do it.

Comment: @Navdroid what you are asking in not the answer to your question. Your http problem is solved. What you were missing then was the way to use the HTTP response content. This is a distinct issue. Shouldn't it be better to update  or split your question?

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping with something like org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider escaping the backslash in the URL. I Java, the backslash must be escaped in a String
It should become

```
String urltext =
            "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=1+2%20\\frac{3}{4}";
```

This was for the pure java start.
It seems that this url works with my browser but, as suggested in the other answers, I think it should be better to also escape all the special characters such as backslashes, laces...